# "Imagine there is ... " or "Imagine that there is ... "? Which option is better?

Tags: ellipses

Which one is the better choice at the beginning of a sentence:

> Imagine there is ...

or

> Imagine **that** there is ...

Comment: Either one. But that is an ELL question. I prefer shorter: Imagine there is.

Comment: They are both OK.  "Better" is not something we can answer from the question as you've posed it.

Comment: Ask John Lennon… strictly speaking 'that' is necessary but modern English speakers don't do strict, so it makes no difference